# Options for User Type Name between business and client

Tags: user-behavior, username

My first post here, still trying to get how to make a good question because most of the answers are a little subjective. anyway.

I'm having a issue close to this others, but none of the others has a answer that fit for me.

- [Good Name for Non-Business](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/27769/110833)
- [Different login business and not business](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46148/differentiating-login-signposting-for-business-and-non-business-users)
- R[egister Business of personal best practice](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/43394/differentiating-between-register-your-business-and-register-yourself-as-indiv)

**My problem is** I have a app with Business and Clients login, but we really don't wanna use this names (B2C). So for business we are using Users Pro (or Providers) but **for Clients still don't get the right name**.

Already thought about members, companyName+Ers. And "user" I'm trying to avoid because the Providers are users to.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Are you saying that a Provider/Client would sign in under a business name but you want to display a friendlier name?

Comment: Curious as to _why_ you'd want to differentiate between B2B and B2C? Presumably, you know the type of account from the user id/email and would be able to show the correct section/homepage?

Comment: @painclothes no, Just wanna better names for Business and Clients.

Comment: @Timo maybe I was not clear hahaha. The issue here is not about B2C or B2B, but the names for B2C. Other names for Business and Clients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Seagate](https://www.seagate.com/consumer/) uses the idea of having users "sign in as" a certain type of account.

> [image: Sign in as]

#### Ensure users recognize what type they're trying to sign in to.

I've never had any issue recognizing that I'm a "Consumer" and should sign in as that type, but I *have* had an issue with somehow winding up on another user type's login page (perhaps through a Google search). I attempted to log in a few times before I realized that I'm not where I should be.

I'd recommend that you **highlight the type of account** your users are attempting to log in as **after a failed login** so that they have a chance to fix this issue as quick as possible.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm0IPQ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

What about **Business/Company login** and **Individual customer/Private user**?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use names like **Private** or **Corporate**